# PHP - Add function data with dots

Tags: php, function

**I have this working sample code as an example...**

```
function get_childs() {
    $array = array(1 => 'item1', 2 => 'item2', 3 => 'item3');
    return $array;
}

function add( $array, $item ) {
    $array[] = $item;
    return $array;
}

function array_delete( $array, $key ) {
    unset( $array[$key] );
    return $array;
}

$result_array = array_delete( add( get_childs(), 'test' ), 2 );
print_r( $result_array );
```

**Change to arrows instead**

Right now a part of the code looks like this (quite ugly):

```
array_delete( add( get_childs(), 'test' ), 2 );
```

I have seen on the web that it is possible to do it someting like this instead:

```
get_childs().add('test').delete(2);
```

*Much more beautiful. **How is it done?***

**A sidenote**

I have seen that the functions called this way can be repeated like this:

```
get_childs().add('something1').add('something2').add('something3');
```

Comment: In PHP `get_childs().add('something1').add('something2').add('something3');` shall look as `get_childs()->add('something1')->add('something2')->add('something3');`

Comment: You probably noticed method chaining in JQuery http://is.gd/EOoIaX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is move this functionality to class, eg:

```
class MyCollection
{
    private $arr;

    public function create_childs()
    {
        $this->arr = array(1 => 'item1', 2 => 'item2', 3 => 'item3');
        return $this;
    }

    public function get_childs()
    {
        return $this->arr;
    }

    public function add($item)
    {
        $this->arr[] = $item;
        return $this;
    }

    public function delete($key)
    {
        unset($this->arr[$key]);
        return $this;
    }

}

$collection = new MyCollection();
print_r($collection->create_childs()->add("test")->delete(2)->get_childs());
```